# did any body notice the recent .Net Framework 4.0 Platform Update 1?

Tags: frameworks, .net-4.0, platform

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx

My questions for understanding,

let us say this is the first time we hear from Microsoft saying .Net has some thing for Hardware specific. (Since they emerge for Azure stuff) "The .NET Framework 4 Platform Update 1"

so does it mean like the work-flow classes listed under State Machine Work-flows, will not be available in other .Net Framework 4.0 flavor like Client Profile, Full 4.0 ?

If it is available with them also, what could be the difference between them?

For example look this Activity definition : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.nativeactivity.aspx

There is Version Information and Platform, and there is no "The .NET Framework 4 Platform Update 1" related reference :)

Are they finding difficulty in referring two platforms?

Edit: What do they actually mean by the word "Platform" ?

Answer (score 0):

It's explained quite nicely here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/04/18/microsoft-net-framework-4-platform-update-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you get the "hardware-specific" idea.  They're simply adding support for SQL Azure to the existing support for MSSQL in WWF.

No, it appears that the state machine workflows will not be available in the **Framework 4** profiles; they've added new profiles: *Framework 4 Client Profile Platform Update 1* and *Framework 4 Profile Update 1* (full).  You'd have to deploy the update to any system where you expected to target the platform update profiles.

Comment: i got from here what is a platform http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110890/difference-between-framework-and-platform :)

Comment: @sahridhayan - I mean, where in the article? It looks like to me they are including the Visual Studio tooling in "platform" as there don't appear to be any hardware-specific or CLR/DLR updates.

Comment: I dont straightaway mean that there are Hardware Specific features. Since they used the word Platform, to me it sounds like some thing which i can refer to a description which is stated in the above SO link. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems some body tried to answer this

"A Call to Action on .NET Versioning
For developers' sake, Microsoft should use sensible, simples names for .NET Framework and other product releases"

http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/call-action-net-versioning-140084